# Sorting MongoDB collection by same key with different values

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I am trying to query my Mongo database to display all values from a certain collection, sorted by all the values of a certain key. For example, I have the collection:

```
{
  "id":"1235432",
  "name":"John Smith",
  "occupation":"janitor",
  "salary":"30000"
},
{
  "id":"23412312",
  "name":"Mathew Colins",
  "occupation":"janitor"
  "salary":"32000"
},
{
  "id":"7353452",
  "name":"Depp Jefferson",
  "occupation":"janitor"
  "salary":"33000"
},
{
  "id":"342434212",
  "name":"Clara Smith",
  "occupation":"Accountant",
  "salary":"45000"
},
{
  "id":"794563452",
  "name":"Jonathan Drako",
  "occupation":"Accountant",
  "salary":"46000"
},
{
  "id":"8383747",
  "name":"Simon Well",
  "occupation":"Accountant",
  "salary":"41000"
}
```

and I am trying to display only the **TOP 2** with highest salary by occupation. My query looks something like this at the moment:

```
Stats.find({occupation:{$exists:true}}).populate('name').sort({salary:1}).limit(2)
```

by that only returns only 1 result instead of one from each occupation.

> How can I change my query to display the top 2 of each occupation by salary range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$aggregate` as mentioned below.

```
 db.collectionName.aggregate({$match:{occupation:{$exists:true}}},
    { $sort: {"salary":-1}},
    { $limit: 2},
   { $project: {"name":1,"salary":1,_id:0} })
```

**Output JSON:**

```
{"name" : "Jonathan Drako",
"salary" : "46000"},
{"name" : "Clara Smith",
"salary" : "45000"}
```

Comment: I am trying to output top 2 with highest salary, displaying salary and name.

Comment: To display salary and name you need to $project both field. I have updated my answer check now.

Comment: thanks! That is quite useful. Can I just ask you about the "failedToParse" error which comes after aggregating the database.

Comment: You can accept this answer and ask a separate question for the issue. It will help another developer also for a particular issue.